# Can't get javascriptRoutes to work with Play Framework 2

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework-2.0, url-routing

I'm trying to use `javascriptRoutes` in Play 2 (Scala) and I am getting an error (see below). Here is what I did:

#### Add `javascriptRoutes` method to `Application` controller

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(Orders.searchProducts))
        .as("text/javascript")
}
```

#### Add route to `routes` file

```
GET    /assets/javascripts/routes    controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

#### Add `<script>` import to `main.scala.html`

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
...
</head>
```

With these changes in place I am getting the following error in the JavaScript console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/routes 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsRoutes is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: so the code compiles but you are seeing errors only after you try to use Orders.searchProducts? Checked your code and worked for me, are u running play with play ~run ?

Comment: yes the code compiles, I see these errors in console of chrome dev. tools and it's not when I try to use Orders.searchProducts, but simply when the page where I included `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>` is loaded. I use play run not play ~run.....

Comment: hmm. well thats weird, I made new project using play 2.1.0 - copy&pasted your lines of code and tested with chrome, no problem - all works.

Comment: And the trick behind play ~run is that it compiles the code every time when you save your files, especially when you change routes that they could work. Just to make sure, shutdown your server, type play clean and then play ~run (in command line ofc)- if that doesnt work, only thing left what comes to my mind is the play version.

Comment: I don't know if you resolved your issue, but I had the same behavior and it was simply because the Javascript route was defined __after__ the route for static resources in my routes file.

Answer (score 6):

wrong order within the **conf/routes** file may cause the issue.

there is a hint:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/1348rbs2vk/2-1-scala-javascript-router-404

once I adjusted the order according to the hint:

> Move the route definition of the javascript router action above the
>   assets route.

the issue was fixed.

```
    # Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

    GET     /                           controllers.MainController.index()
    GET     /message                    controllers.MessageController.getMessage()
    GET     /assets/javascripts/routes  controllers.MessageController.javascriptRoutes()

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    GET     /webjars/*file              controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)`
```

Comment: +1 I had the same problem in my Play 2 (Java) app, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. Actually for me I had to delete in intellJ the submodule-build items in project config. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676311/unable-to-resolve-reverse-routing-methods-in-intellij

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I have found an other post related to this ->

[Unable to resolve reverse routing methods in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676311/unable-to-resolve-reverse-routing-methods-in-intellij)

I had to remove some info from the project config to get the following folders to become part of source route ->

File -> Project Structure

Select Sources in Right Pane

Add Source folder
target/scala-XXX/classes_managed
target/scala-XXX/src_managed/main