# Unable to resolve reverse routing methods in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm following one of the play framework tutorials, but I'm getting compile errors whenever I try to use reverse routing. Firstly,

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
            controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.add(),
            controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.delete(),
            controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.rename(),
            controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.addGroup()
        )
    );
}
```

where the error shown in intelliJ is 'cannot resolve method javascriptRouter(java.lang.String, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

But also in the a unit test:

```
@Test
public void notAuthenticated() {
    Result result = callAction(
            controllers.routes.ref.Application.index(),
            fakeRequest()
    );
    assertEquals(303, status(result));
    assertEquals("/login", header("Location", result));
}
```

where it cannot resolve the index method.

Is this a problem with intelliJ, or am I missing something within play?

For the first part, here is the entry in my routes file:

```
GET     /assets/javascripts/routes  controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

and my controller, Projects, has got the defined methods.

Comment: Seems there are no such methods defined.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're just being a smart-ass, but I edited my question to include a segment of the routes file. Also, my Application has an index method. I know because it renders the home page.

Comment: Please link the Play tutorial where this code comes from.

Comment: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1-RC2/JavaGuide6
This is part six or the tutorial. The relevant part is at the top.

Comment: I have no problem, try ignoring the error at first, run `play compile` on your console an check IntelliJ again. Besides, a tip: write @nkr somewhere in your comment so I get a notice you replied.

Comment: I'm having this same issue with my project in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.13 and most new version of Play framework.

Comment: Having the same error "Cannot resolve method 'routes'", yet the server works perfectly as intended.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**File** -> **Project Structure**

Select **Sources** in Right Pane

Add Source folder

*target/scala-XXX/classes_managed*

*target/scala-XXX/src_managed/main*

Comment: Worked for me too. Similar issue and solutions in this response to [IntelliJ IDEA Report Highlighting error when using routes in Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398590/1124740)

Comment: The target directory is generated, right? Then, this fix would be undone every time the project is cleaned?

Answer (score 22):

I was running into the same problem and found the solution here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/969

In short:

- Create the directories `javascript` and `ref` under the controllers package
- Run `activator compile` and now Intellij should get it  *// used to be 'play compile'*
- If you still got the errors try to run `activator idea` again // used to be 'play compile'*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I first run `play idea` and then created the folders, and the compile error was gone like magic. Not sure if the order matters.

Comment: This is generally the right answer but a few clarifications:

- Add the 'javascript' and 'ref' folders under /app/controllers
- the 'play' command has been replaced by 'activator'

My order of operations was 1) add directories, 2) activator idea, and 3) activator compile

Doing a 'rebuild' in IntelliJ requires 'activator compile' to be run again. Annoying.

Comment: Actually you should add javascript and ref dirs to target/scala-xxx/src_managed/main/controllers

Answer (score 6):

Pulled from a link provided by @Markus Kittig. Great temporary fix. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1784#issuecomment-26345523

Synopsis:
Add target/scala-XXX as a managed source and remove the app controllers and views sources flag inside File->Project Structure->Modules->Sources. Then recompile.

Works on IntelliJ Ultimate 12.1.{4|6}. Created the play application with the command line interface and generated a project file using `play idea`.  Used Play 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

With IntelliJ 14.1 and Play 2.3.8 nothing of the above worked, but the advice from this [mailing list](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/151vc026y5/intellij-idea-play-framework-2-3-7-issues) worked. (Almost) blatantly copied:

> Locate the target/scala-2.11/src_managed and target/scala-2.11/twirl
>   directories in the project view, then right click and Mark Directory
>   As -> Generated Sources *(Root)*.

I bumped the scala version and obviously in newer versions of IntelliJ the *Root* word has been added. Also, you cannot select this from the Project Structure window, the option is not available. It is possible only through the `Project` pane in the main window. If it refuses to be marked as `Generated Sources`, try to unmark the`target` directory (Mark Directory As -> Unmark ).

Answer (score 4):

For people using Play 2.4.x or above, it seems that Play no longer produces reverse routing files for javascript in `src_managed` et al.

Instead, you need to include `scala-2.xx/routes/main` directory as `Sources`.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a year ago, but to answer for future queries by other coders, the problem is easily solved by adding a "play.Routes" path like this

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
            play.Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",

                    // Routes for Projects
                    controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.add(),
                    controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.delete(),
                    controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.rename(),
                    controllers.routes.javascript.Projects.addGroup()
            )
    );
```

}

Ensure that you have the proper imports to the class:

```
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Idea 14.1.4 community edition, i managed to remove the index and route not resolved errors by right clicking on the target folder and marking it as not excluded. NB i run my project using the command line i can not find any run configuration in the ide.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find that folders in my PLay 2.8 build, so as it was a problem with IntelliJ I found an easier solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70339356/2367237