# IntelliJ IDEA Report Highlighting error when using routes in Controller

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

I have a Scala Play project. I'm using Play 2.2.1. I downloaded Scala, Play 2 supported and SBT plugins. Everything is OK, but When I call route on Action in the Controller appear following error(Look screenshots):

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6 Ultimate version. Scala version 2.10.2

Anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

> **Edit**

When I generate my project to Intellij IDEA via "play idea" command in play console, and I opened project in IDEA project structure was such:

[image: screenshot6]

Then I saw answer @millhouse and discussing on this githup([[Play 2.2] "play idea" creates not working source mapping in target](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1784)) and I removed following folders from **Sources Folders**:

> - target\scala-2.10\src_managed\main\controllers
> - target\scala-2.10\src_managed\main\views

**and "Report highlighting error" disappeared, but now there is another error:**

[image: screenshot3]

**and**

[image: screenshot7]

**my route:**

[image: screenshot4]

And I've changed "Sources Folders" as shown below:

[image: screenshot5]

**But it doesn't help me. And remains "Unspecified value parametrs" error.**

Comment: Upgrade to Intellij IDEA 13 and use `File -> Import Project` and select `SBT project`. Generating the idea files with `play idea` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Here's bug report for that: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1784

Comment: This might be related to the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7726

Answer (score 50, accepted):

millhouse's answer helped me find the right answer.  Play 2.2 (and perhaps earlier versions, haven't checked) output a scala version of the routes file to `project_dir/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main` So for IntelliJ to get the highlighting right you need to make sure that `src_managed/main` is added as a source folder.  The reverse routes for javascript are for some reason included in `project_dir/target/scala-2.10/classes_managed` so you'll have to add that as well. (In your screenshot it looks like `classes_managed` is set to excluded so you'll want to un-exclude it by pressing the x button on the right hand side.)

Here's a screen shot of my project structure:

[image: Working Play 2.2 project structure]

**Update**:

In Play 2.3 (or perhaps recent versions of IntelliJ) adding the classes_managed no longer fixes the problem.  Instead of adding classes_managed to the project's sources add it to it's dependencies.  By doing that IntelliJ should be able to pick up the compiled routes.class.

[image: Working Play 2.3 dependency list]

Comment: If you still get errors doing a File>Invalidate Caches and a restart might help.

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked like a charm!

Comment: I don't have `classes_managed` folder (play-scala-intro template, Play 2.4.1) :(

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what I have to do to get it working with Play 2.4...

Comment: @wm_eddie: try re-importing the project from scratch, i.e. delete / rename the .idea subdirectory & re-follow the instructions on: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html#import_project - resolved the issue in my case. Seems like there may have been some crud left behind when upgrading IDEA / Play.

Comment: For Play 2.3 you have to mark src_managed/main folder as source to get route package recognized, works for me with IntelliJ 2016.1.1

Answer (score 8):

This is a common problem, it's because IntelliJ needs to be shown where to look for the *compiled* Scala templates and `routes` file. Here's how I fixed it on my IntelliJ 12.1 installation:

- Go to the Module Settings for your project in IntelliJ (select the top-level, hit F4)
- Choose the Modules item in the Project Structure window that appears
- Select the *projectname* item (as opposed to the *projectname-build* item)
- Add the compiler's output directory to the **Source Folders** items;

  - For Scala 2.10 it's `target/scala-2.10/classes`
  - I personally find the IntelliJ UI for this to be very non-intuitive; you might need to take the `target` directory and/or one of its subdirectories out of the **Excluded Folders** first
- After applying that change, IntelliJ should see the results of compiling each `routes` and `.scala.html` file as just-another source file, so they won't show as "broken" and auto-complete should work for them.

Comment: @ Millhouse Why should only add "target/scala-2.10/classes/views" in the sources folder? Why do not you add "target/scala-2.10/classes/controllers" and "target/scala-2.10/classes/models" folder Sources Folder?

Comment: @mr.boyfox You're right, I've updated my answer so that your `routes`, and `.scala.html` template files should all get picked up.

Comment: Thanks @millhouse, I tried this but appear another error, please see my edit