# IntelliJ Idea sbt managed source file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I am using [sbt-buildinfo plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) that generates Scala source from my build definitions, allowing me to reference project name, version, etc. from my Scala code.

It does this by generating a file **BuiltInfo.scala** with the following contents:

```
package hello

case object BuildInfo {
  val name = "helloworld"
  val version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  val scalaVersion = "2.10.3"
  val sbtVersion = "0.13.2"
}
```

in

**target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/sbt-buildinfo/BuildInfo.scala**.

Everything compiles and I can reference those vals.

However, IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize BuildInfo.scala as a managed source file, so that it would stop showing me errors. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ and Scala plugin are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea 13.0.3, not sure about the Scala plugin. Where can I check that?

Comment: Sadly, this is still a problem two years later. :(

Comment: is it still a problem in 2017.1?

Answer (score 7):

[Grega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587408/grega-ke%c5%a1pret), are you working in a Play Framework project? Or do you have any SBT sub-projects? I don't have a complete answer, but may have a lead.

This same problem shows up in my IDEA projects when using [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) *and* [sbt-scalaxb](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb). Frustratingly, it has worked intermittently—usually after lots of tinkering around, but inexplicably stops.

I wound up digging a bit deeper (and eventually issued bug report [SCL-7182](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7182) to JetBrains), and noticed the root cause was having a sub-project. When present, IDEA doesn't correctly identify `src_managed` for the root project, but *does* for the sub-project.

A work-around, for now, is to manually add the correct `src_managed` directory to your project's sources using the Project Structure dialog.

For reference, I'm running version 0.38.437 of the Scala plugin on IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3.

Comment: Also, see the answers to [_IntelliJ IDEA Report Highlighting error when using routes in Controller_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398590/700420).

Comment: I also had to remove the exclusion on `/target` in a subproject to get this to work.  Then I had to unmark `src_managed/main` as sources, and then mark `src_managed/main/java` as sources.

Comment: same problem still here after 3 years and with idea 2019.3, sbt 1.3