# sbt-buildinfo generated object cannot be referenced

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I'm using the aforementioned sbt plugin to get the version of the app I'm working on.

The project has sub-modules. Here is the main `build.sbt`

```
...

lazy val abandon = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(base, cli, gui).
  dependsOn(base, cli, gui).
  enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "abandon",
    fork in run := true,
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
    buildInfoPackage := "co.uproot.abandon"
  )

lazy val base = (project in file("base")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "abandon-base",
    fork in run := true
  )


lazy val cli = (project in file("cli")).
  dependsOn(base).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "abandon-cli",
    fork in run := true
  )

lazy val gui = (project in file("gui")).
  dependsOn(base).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "abandon-gui",
    fork in run := true
  )
```

The generated `BuildInfo.scala` is located under `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-buildinfo/BuildInfo.scala` as expected.

```
package co.uproot.abandon

import scala.Predef._

/** This object was generated by sbt-buildinfo. */
case object BuildInfo {
  /** The value is "abandon". */
  val name: String = "abandon"
  /** The value is "0.3.1". */
  val version: String = "0.3.1"
  /** The value is "2.11.8". */
  val scalaVersion: String = "2.11.8"
  /** The value is "0.13.12". */
  val sbtVersion: String = "0.13.12"
  override val toString: String = {
    "name: %s, version: %s, scalaVersion: %s, sbtVersion: %s" format (
      name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion
    )
  }
}
```

When I go to a file inside the `package co.uproot.abandon` and try to reference `BuildInfo.version` I get

```
Error:(256, 42) object BuildInfo is not a member of package co.uproot.abandon
    co.uproot.abandon.BuildInfo.version
```

I read about the problem with submodules and this plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250962/1450817) and ultimately tried [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9301#comment=27-1284275) workaround but that didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I have a project with a *very* similar setup, and I'm not having a problem. After configuring it as you have here, have you tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart` in your IntelliJ 'File' menu? What version of IntelliJ/SBT/Scala etc. are you using?

Comment: @NathanielFord I just did that per your suggestion and it didn't help. For reference I use: 
IntelliJ - **2016.2.5**
SBT - **0.13.12**
Scala - **2.11.6**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved.

Just make sure to set the `main` part of `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-buildinfo/BuildInfo.scala` as source in the Project structure **for the particular sub-module** you would like to use it for and **not** the whole project.

Other than that the syntax highlighting is screwed so it will show up the same way as before i.e. when it wasn't compiling. To avoid that follow the link in **this** that I posted in the question.

Comment: Ah! Glad you found an answer: it would have been clear if you had indicated which project you'd been referencing from (I had assumed root based on the package). You should add a working config to your answer for future folks!

Comment: Thanks +1. Moreover, I just added an answer with screenshots to illustrate a little bit more.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add an image to illustrate `zaxme` answer, but I can't in the comments, so I am adding another answer to add more information about it.

---

So,

1 - Right click on `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main`:

[image]

---

And,

2 - Select `Mark Directory as` and `Unmark Generated Sources Root`:

[image]

---

Then rebuild, it should work.

Comment: What worked for me was to Mark Directory as Excluded  (Nice to see you here @axel-borja ;-) )

Comment: You probably right, the both should work (Ahah, yes definitely :))