# IntelliJ Idea can't resolve symbol that inside Scala managed sources (sbt-buildinfo)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt-plugin, sbt-buildinfo

I think it could be a problem that appeared in new versions, and can't be resolved as old versions, I got a Play Java project with `sbt-buildinfo` plugin the problem is really common is that IntelliJ keep saying it can't resolve that symbol

[image: InjettiJ can't resolve symbol]

And here is the file:

[image: Generated file]

Some solutions can be found [IntelliJ Idea sbt managed source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957955/intellij-idea-sbt-managed-source-file) and here [sbt-buildinfo generated object cannot be referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227891/sbt-buildinfo-generated-object-cannot-be-referenced) but none of the solutions provided were helpful for me:

[image: InjelliJ settings]

The really strange thing is if I "Unmark the directory as a generated source" and then move that `BuildInfo.scala` file to the package folder manually to `buildpkg` (my custom package) instead of `sbt-buildinfo` package, IntelliJ see that file, but this change is useless because the file will be generated again and all changes will be discarded:

[image: Wow!]

Here is my **build.sbt**:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion, buildInfoBuildNumber,
      "hostname" -> java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName,
      "gitHash" -> sys.env.getOrElse("BITBUCKET_COMMIT", "No BITBUCKET_COMMIT set")
    ),
    buildInfoPackage := "buildpkg",
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson,
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.BuildTime
  )

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
```

and my **plugins.sbt** :

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.7.0")
```

So what I'm missing, what the solution for this

Comment: can you try setting `buildInfoUsePackageAsPath := true` and see if that helps?

Comment: @JustinKaeser this is awesome, this is worked! wow! please add answer so I accept it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In the sbt settings in IntelliJ, enable the settings "Use sbt shell for build and import", since the sources are generated only when sbt runs the build.
2. IntelliJ will currently only correctly update generated sources if they are in the correct package directory. For sbt-buildinfo, add the setting

   `buildInfoUsePackageAsPath := true`

   to your `build.sbt`.

Comment: You can find the option `use sbt shell for build and import`, in `IntelliJ` -> `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `sbt`.

Answer (score -2):

This issue will also occur if the SBT based project is not "imported" in the first place.

To try to fix this issue:

1. Close the IntelliJ project in question.
2. Select Import Project
3. In the Import Project dialog box, select "Import project from external model"
4. Select "sbt". Note that "Use sbt shell for build..." is not required to be checked. If you do not click this, you can still take advantage of autoload. Be sure Library sources are checked.

Press Finish and let it build what it needs to now load the plugins and such for the first time.

Comment: Actually, it was imported correctly and auto-import was checked already, otherwise, the project would be full of errors of unseen packages and classes, please read the question again, you can see IntelliJ simply recognized the project :) thanks. anyway, Justin answer was the solution, to be exact, this line solved my issue here `buildInfoUsePackageAsPath := true` everything was correctly set already.