# How to properly import a Play 2+ project in IntelliJ 14+ with all integrated features (run, debug, test)?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I work on a Java based Play! project for severals months now and I'd like to import it completely in IntelliJ, meaning being able to run, compile, test and debug from IntelliJ, without the need to use the command line.

According to [this post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/) from Jetbrain, it seems to be possible, if I quote the article it says clearly : "Now you don’t need to switch between IntelliJ IDEA and Play console anymore. Everything is available right from your favorite IDE.", but I can't figure out a way to achieve this for now, even if I follow the tutorial provided by Jetbrains.

Here are the steps I've been throught :

1. Open my fav IDE IntelliJ ;)
2. Go to the project list window.
3. Import project
4. Import from external model and choose SBT as suggested in Jetbrains tutorial.
5. option "Use auto import" checked, option "create directories for empty content roots automatically" checked. Project SDK Java 1.7
6. Global sbt settings : JVM From project JDK.
7. Finish

By now, if I try to make the project and launch it from IntelliJ, I'll get scala compiling errors related to routes object. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235700/intellij-idea-report-highlighting-error-when-using-routes-in-controller), we can understand that this happens because scala routes are located to specific folders that needs to be included in IntelliJ sources settings for this project. So next step was :

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules
2. Add target/scala-2.10/classes:target/scala-2.10/resources_managed:target/scala-2.10/src_managed as sources folders.

But my problem remains the same, routes object being unrecognized.

Notes : I have no scala facets in my project structure configuration nor can add one.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ provides integrated support for the Play Framework for Scala and Java. Support is currently only available in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition (see the [Frameworks and Technology](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) section).

Assuming Ultimate Edition, the setup for Play is incredibly easy. Simply create a new project by importing `build.sbt`, then choose *Add Framework Support* and choose *Play 2*.

Once complete, you can start and stop Play using the Play 2 *Run/Debug configuration*. No command line necessary.

[Here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0) is a more in depth look at IntelliJ's Play project configuration.

Comment: I have no build.sbt file in my project, you mean Build.scala ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the command `play idea` if you are using play or `activator idea` if you are using activator. That will do the magic.

Comment: This is not the recommended way by Jetbrains on their blog, could you detail some more the steps you've gone through to make it work ? Thanks

Comment: how it is not recommended way? could you please send the link of the jetbrains blog?

Comment: The first link of my post brings you to an article that points to this tutorial : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0

Comment: but this doesnt mean you cant use activator idea command, you could try it: from terminal go to the path of the project and try the command.

Comment: I don't have `idea` task. Why you guys have it? `not a valid command: idea (similar: gen-idea, eval, alias)`