# IntelliJ IDEA reports errors in routes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, typesafe-activator

1. I've created a project by `activator new play-scala-intro play-scala-intro`
2. In IDEA I've clicked `File` -> `Import project from Existing sources` and selected `SBT`.

[image]

This is default project structure:
[image: dfdfdf]

I've also tried all tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235700/intellij-idea-report-highlighting-error-when-using-routes-in-controller) (suggested for for Play 2.2 — 2.3, whereas I have Play 2.4). But I haven't tried to add `target/scala-*/classes_managed` to sources because my project doesn't contain this folder.

### Versions

- I have Idea 14 Ultimate with installed "Scala" and "Playframework support" plugins.
- Play Framework: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.1")`
- `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"`

Answer (score 5):

JetBrains hasn't yet updated their Scala/Play plugin to reflect the new routing structure with Play 2.4 (using classes instead of objects for the controllers, for example).  You can ignore those errors, run the app and it'll be all fine.

See the ongoing issue ticket over on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8812 for more. One comment says: "This got fixed in the recent EAP Build of IntelliJ and Scala 1.6.27.1.EAP also IntelliJ EAP 15 looks really good in his current state."

You can wait for IntelliJ 15. In the meanwhile, ignore the errors which are wrongly flagged by IntelliJ 14 and older versions.

Comment: Actually there are also multiple errors in `.scala` files related to work with routes which is hardly to ignore. Is there a way to get old version of template? (Simple cloning of `/templates/play-scala-intro` doesn't work because of postprocessing is omitted in this case)

Comment: Unfortunately still the same errors on IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP (build 142.2670.3).

Comment: What version of the Scala plugin is your IDEA 15 EAP using?

Answer (score 3):

My IntelliJ IDEA version is 14.1.4, add a `@` symbol before the `controllers` like this:

```
GET         /                    @controllers.Application.index
```

The IDE won't report a `Cannot resolve ...` message.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation Play documentation for 2.4 version here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting it specifically states that -

> Play supports generating two types of routers, one is a dependency injected router, the other is a static router. The default is the static router, but if you created a new Play application using the Play seed Activator templates, your project will include the following configuration in build.sbt telling it to use the injected router:
>
> routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

Hence if you check you build.sbt, it would have a line -

`routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator`

Indicating that the default router is the dependency injected router.

Hence to avoid the error, you would have to append @ to the controllers in the routes file as stated here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting -

> The code samples in Play’s documentation assumes that you are using the injected routes generator. If you are not using this, you can trivially adapt the code samples for the static routes generator, either by prefixing the controller invocation part of the route with an @ symbol, or by declaring each of your controllers as an object rather than a class.