# Using Apache Spark MLib Libraries without Spark Console

Tags: java, python, scala, machine-learning, apache-spark

I installed `Apache Spark` on `Windows 7` and successfully got both the `Scala` and `Python` consoles to run..

My question is to know if using the console is necessary when simply wanting to utilize the `Mlib` (Machine Learning Library) directly from a Scala, Java or Python installation when not using the Spark Console.

Is there a simple way to do this, and are there major reasons why I might not want to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093870/intellij-idea-reports-errors-in-routeshttps://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8812

Comment: That's a bad link.. actually two URLs in one line.. I checked both and don't quite see the connection

Answer (score 3):

Of course you don't have to use console. You can create **Spark context** in your code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Spark Pi")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
```

then create **RDD**:

```
val data = spark.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
```

and run Mlib algorithms on it.