# Play Framework tutorial: Cannot resolve symbol 'routes'

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am following the [play tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/) and I am stuck at roughly 9 mins. The routes file is not getting resolved I did the same thing as shown in the tutorial but still doesn't work.

```
package controllers;
import models.Bar;
import play.core.Router;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc;
import play.*;
import play.Routes;
import views.html.indes;
public class Application extends Controller {

public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Hello"));
}

public static Result addBar(){
    Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    bar.save();
    return redirect(routes)
    }

}
```

Comment: share routes file, URL being accessed and what you see in the logs/console

Comment: also, share your index.scala.html file (unless you're using a different templating mechanism)

Comment: I am unable to resolve routes. can anyone please help me out asap?

Comment: routes file 

# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /bars                       controllers.Application.addBar()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

Comment: URl tring to access is localhost:/9000; In the logs it says that it cannot resolve routes

Comment: index.scala.html file --------------- @(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @message

}

Comment: add your file info in the post as an update (and marked as code for better readability). You need to spend more time going through the docs.  This index scala template gets used when you access the following in your browser (localhost:9000 - not localhost:/9000)

Comment: do you have a main.scala.html - you can always just keep the index simple and put in a single line of html.  Also, can you show the full stack of the error message as an update in your question

Comment: I am having Intellij 15, Play 2.4.6 framework. I am also getting this same error of `cannot resolve symbol routes`. How to get resolved with this ? Please help.

Answer (score 6):

```
Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + -> JAR or directories -> target/scala-#.##/classes_managed
```

Marking this directory as Sources Root/Generated Sources Root did not work for me, as mentioned in some other S/O posts

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the specific instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It was localhost:9000 itself. I dint try running the server again.
Actually the code is not able to identify the routes file which is under conf. I am just trying to replicate whatever is shown in the tutorial but it's not happening!

Answer (score 1):

These steps work for me:

1. Add following lines to your plugins.sbt file:
   `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")` under project folder.
2. Remove .idea folder from your project.
3. Run the command from cmd `sbt gen-idea`
4. Import project again in intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem every time I change the scala version of my modules. The easiest way to solve this is:

- Close Intellij
- Open a console and run `sbt clean compile`
- Open the IDE again and it should work

Answer (score -2):

Based on the information you provided, you need to use the following URL:

```
localhost:9000
```

not localhost:/9000.  The URL above should trigger the index method (inside the Application controller) to be called.  Based on the implementation you shared, it will result in the index template to be used to render the view (with a 200 HTTP response).  Make sure that you have index.scala.template in the views directory.