# IntelliJ Ultimate can't find routes in Play 2.3 (Java) project tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

While my tests run just fine, IntelliJ complains that it can't find the routes object and code auto complete fails to work. I've looked all over the documentation and this should just work. Here is what IntelliJ is reporting

[image: error from intellij]

Any thoughts as to what might be wrong with my project configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's connected with the fact that the **routes** object is generated during project compilation. After compilation, it should be placed under the `target/scala-{ver}/src_managed` directory. Mark this directory as source and IntelliJ should see routes correctly.

You can use one of the following steps to do it:

- right-click the directory in the Project view and select `Mark Directory As -> Generated Sources Root`

or

- open `File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> Sources` and mark the `src_managed` directory as Sources using the button above the project structure

Comment: Worked like a charm! The only issue now is that IntelliJ complains that my controller methods don't exist. Any idea what the issue is there? Once that's fixed I'll be more than happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Never mind, I found another directory to mark as source. Accepted!

Comment: @Zarathuztra what directory did you mark to resolve it? I get the same complaints about not existing methods after adding src_managed/main to sources

Comment: @Scadge You'll want to look at the ones mentioned above. First run the app to get everything compiled, then mark the src_managed and classes_managed directories as source roots

Answer (score 2):

Actually your question motivated me to find solution for this annoying issue :)

And actually it was already answered, see this answer which works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879374/1066240

Also read other answers and comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This actually helped me solve my secondary problem