# Remove error-indication in IntelliJ in Play Framework project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, playframework, terminal

My method in my Application-class shows an error in IntelliJ that isn't an error. The method works fine in my browser and as you know (if you're familiar with Play) compile-errors will show in your browser when you run the program. My method works just as planned, but the error-indication in the IDE won't go away.

If you use Eclipse (Scala IDE) you just run the `activator eclipse` command in the command-line and the IDE won't complain anymore - is there a similar fix for IntelliJ?

Edit: I use Play 2.4, so the `activator idea` command doesn't work either: [Play Framework 2.4 and IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605802/play-framework-2-4-and-intellij-idea)

Edit 2: Not a duplicate of [IntelliJ Ultimate can't find routes in Play 2.3 (Java) project tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355565/intellij-ultimate-cant-find-routes-in-play-2-3-java-project-tests) because that one is about the IDE not finding routes, and mine is about wrong error-indication with different solutions to different problems. For the correct solution see the accepted answer.

Comment: What kind of errors do you mean?

Comment: @DanielOlszewski Cannot resolve method: http://kollstrom.net/error-indication.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Ultimate can't find routes in Play 2.3 (Java) project tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355565/intellij-ultimate-cant-find-routes-in-play-2-3-java-project-tests)

Comment: @DanielOlszewski This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355565/intellij-ultimate-cant-find-routes-in-play-2-3-java-project-tests
This is a Play 2.4 specific problem as the accepted answer pointed out, and the problem in your referred post is from 2.3. Also my problem had a "Cannot resolve method"-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IDEA 14.1.3 doesn't set the classpath correctly when importing a Play 2.4 application. By default `target` folder is excluded from the classpath. However the twirl templates and routes are compiled to the target folder and need to be available to the classpath.

To fix the issue

1. Make sure your classes and templates are compiled: `Build > Make`
2. Open `File > Project Structure`
3. Go to `Modules` menu and select the `root` module
4. Go to the `Sources` tab
5. Remove the `target` folder from the excludes by clicking on the `X` next to it in the right panel
6. Click Apply

You can then see that `target\scala-2.11\routes\main` and `target\scala-2.11\twirl\main` are recognized as source folders properly.

Your error should then go away.

Comment: The folders you mentioned are now recognized as source folders, but the error-indication remains. This is how the Sources tab look like: http://kollstrom.net/source.png

Comment: It works if I remove 'views.html' from `views.html.hello.render(name)`, so now it's: `public static Result hello(String name) {return ok(hello.render(name));}`. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, always import views.html.* so that all compiled twirl classes/objects are picked up by IDEA.

Comment: Correct - thank you! This should definitely be included here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE