# play framework javascript Routing Failed to load resource

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to make some Javascript Rounting in my Play Framework app and am running into some errors:

I have a button with the id `#next` which should use Ajax to load some new image and text into a div named `#content`.

In my Application.java I have implemented the following two methods:

```
public static Result nextUser(int i) {
    return ok(content.render(users.get(i)));
}

public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
            Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                    controllers.routes.javascript.Application.nextUser()
            )
    );
}
```

Made this content.scala.html file:

```
@(user: User)
<img id="user" src="@routes.Assets.at(user.getImg())" />
<h2>@user.getStatus()</h2>
```

Added this into to the routes file:

```
GET        /nextuser                    controllers.Application.nextUser(i: Int)

GET        /assets/javascripts/routes   controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

And then tried this Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes()"></script>
<script>
    var userIndex = 1;

    $("#next").click(function() {
        jsRoutes.controllers.Application.nextUser(userIndex).ajax({
        success : function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {

        }
        });
    });

</script>
```

In the Application.java file in the javascriptRoutes Method the controllers.**routes**. can not be found.

Does anybody know what is causing the error?

Edit:

I could solve the initial error thanks to this:
[Unable to resolve reverse routing methods in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676311/unable-to-resolve-reverse-routing-methods-in-intellij)

Now it looks like this:

[image]

The nextUser Method cannot be found even when cleary defined.

When I compile the application using `activator compile` and run it using `activator run` my chrome console looks like this:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/34581c81beda3520f927991c6a0c554f.png]

so still the routes file somehow cant be found.

Comment: Why scala is tagged?

Comment: Could you maybe try to explain better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Use the `JavaScriptReverseRouter` as described in the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJavascriptRouter#Router-resource -- note that the [embedded router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJavascriptRouter#Embedded-router) does not with methods having parameters; you really have to use the `JavaScriptReverseRouter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I could fix the problem thanks to this:

[Can't get javascriptRoutes to work with Play Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905392/cant-get-javascriptroutes-to-work-with-play-framework-2)

The problem was the order in my routes document. As soon as I switched the assets declaration before the javascript routes it worked:

```
# Javascript Router
GET        /assets/javascripts/routes        controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```